# angular 2 subscription doesnt make a change event

Tags: angular

I have made a component that subscribed to a service, and this service is itself filled by another component.

My subscription is working, and I have my this.data_id that is up to date according to the other component, but now I have a little issue remaining.
How to detect that my data_id had changed and reload my item list according to this new id.

I have 2 functions in my code below, ngOnChanges is never called, I havent any log so far for it.

getData() is triggered by a button and work perfectly.
How can I have a behaviour such as ngOnChanges for my data_id that is under a subscription and not a normal input field?

```typescript
import { Component,Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

import {Item,ItemListData,ItemData} from '../itemService';
import {selectedDataService} from '../../../components/data/dataService';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'item-list',
  templateUrl: './itemList.html',
  styleUrls: ['./itemList.scss'],
  providers:[
    ItemListData,
    ItemData
  ]
})
export class ItemListComponent implements OnChanges{

  @Input() data_id : number = null;
  items: Item[];

  subscription : Subscription;



  constructor( private _selectedDataService:selectedDataService) {
    this.subscription = this._selectedDataService.selectedDataItem$.subscribe(data_id => this.data_id = data_id);

  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('onchanges',changes )
    this.getItemList(changes.data_id.currentValue);
  }

  getData(){
    this.getItemList(this.data_id);
  }


  ngOnDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak when component is destroyed
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but if you want to call `getItemList` function each time you're notified by `selectedDataItem$`, why don't you simply call this function inside that subscription like this:

```
this.subscription =
    this._selectedDataService.selectedDataItem$
        .subscribe(data_id => this.getItemList(data_id));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I understand now better how subscription works btw. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value of the data_id input-parameter in the component itself. That's a bad-practice, since it breaks the unidirectional dataflow principle. The values of input parameters should only be set by the parent component.

Where does the getItemList function live? It doesn't appear to be on your component. Anyway, when there is a change detection cycle running, it will check the value of the parent component for input parameters. When you set it these parameters yourself at the same time its logical that you get change detection issues.

Answer (score 0):

The observable and subject or BehavourSubject are two different thing.

You service returns an observable, so you need a subject type variable to access that or in short subscribe them to get data out of it on time intervals.

```
subscription : Subject;
```